# Angular 7 unit testing dependency injection not working in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, dependency-injection, ngoninit

I am using Angular 7 with and Angular CLI version 7.3.4.  I am unit testing a component with 2 service injections all important code is included below. I included the stub which is causing errors, the spec file, and the important part of the component in question. Despite this, I am still getting this error "TypeError: this.spreading.getSpreadingDays is not a function" I am aware that fixture.detectchanges() is what causes ngOnInit to be called, but the function should be defined since I injected the service.  I am sure it is a silly error, but I have looked at a number of tutorials and I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Spec file

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { SpreadSignUpComponent } from './spread-sign-up.component';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/core/services/auth.service';
import { SpreadingService } from 'src/app/core/services/spreading.service';
import { AuthServiceStub } from 'src/app/core/testing/auth.service.stub';
import { SpreadingServiceStub } from 'src/app/core/testing/spreading.service.stub';

describe('SpreadSignUpComponent', () => {
  let component: SpreadSignUpComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SpreadSignUpComponent>;

  let authService: AuthService;
  let spreadingService: SpreadingService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: AuthService, useValue: AuthServiceStub },
        { provide: SpreadingService, useValue: SpreadingServiceStub }
      ],
      declarations: [ SpreadSignUpComponent ],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
    })
    .compileComponents();

    authService = TestBed.get(AuthService);
    spreadingService = TestBed.get(SpreadingService);
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SpreadSignUpComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

stub class:

```
import { SpreadingService } from '../services/spreading.service';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { SpreadingDay } from 'src/app/shared/models/spreadingDay';
import { I } from 'src/app/shared/testing/interfaceBuilder';

export class SpreadingServiceStub implements I<SpreadingService> {

  getSpreadingDays() {
    return of([]);
  }

  getSpreadingDaysForUser() {
    return of([]);
  }

  setSpreadingDay(
    spreadingDay: SpreadingDay
  ) {
    return <Promise<void>>{};
  }

  addVolunteerToDay(
    spreadingDay: SpreadingDay,
    userID: string,
  ) {
    return <Promise<void>>{};
  }

  removeVolunteerFromDay(
    spreadingDay: SpreadingDay,
    userID: string,
  ) {
    return <Promise<void>>{};
  }

  addRequestToDay(
    spreadingDay: SpreadingDay,
    userID: string,
    first: string,
    last: string,
  ) {
    return <Promise<void>>{};
  }
}
```

component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SpreadingService } from 'src/app/core/services/spreading.service';
import { SpreadingDayReturn, SpreadingDay } from 'src/app/shared/models/spreadingDay';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/core/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-spread-sign-up',
  templateUrl: './spread-sign-up.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spread-sign-up.component.scss']
})
export class SpreadSignUpComponent implements OnInit {

  spreadingDays$: Observable<SpreadingDayReturn[]>;

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
    private spreading: SpreadingService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.spreadingDays$ = this.spreading.getSpreadingDays();
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your code `{ provide: SpreadingService, useValue: SpreadingServiceStub }` should be `{ provide: SpreadingService, useClass: SpreadingServiceStub }`. hard to notice mistake. I assume the same should be applied for the second service stub